# How to stop login for SPECIFIC users BEFORE a specified date

Tags: customization, login, permissions

I'm developing a membership website (using Memberpress) and want to send the login information to some users before the site goes live. I want these specific users to be UNABLE to login BEFORE my launch date. All others users - admins, the client, test users that I create - shouldn't be blocked from logging in.

What's the best way to do this?

- Cron job that changes one or more roles of specific users
- some plugin (which I'm not aware of)
- Use ACF to setup a "date" field and run a check on login

Comment: You could give them all a role, and then run a check vs some date at a role on login. Or it might be safer to give all your other non-admin users a beta role, and block non-admin non-beta users before the launch date.

Comment: How you do that is going to depend how you're preventing general access to the site at the moment - via some memberpress thing? Apologies I don't know Memberpress.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so what I ended up doing was removing all roles from users that were already setup. Now when they try to login and visit any of the pages on the website, they can't. On the date I plan to go live, I will manually update their role to an allowed role - not an issue as there are only a handful of users.